# How to add 2 different custom cells in cellforrow?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell-formatting

I have issue, my app crash on `cellForRowAtIdexPath` because I want to add 2 different custom table view cells for 2 different rows.

See my code.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"MatchDetail";
MatchDetailsCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"GoalsList";
GoalsListCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        if (cell1 == nil) {
            cell1 = (MatchDetailsCell *)[MatchDetailsCell cellFromNibNamed:@"MatchDetailsCell"];
        }
        [cell1 setDataInCell:arrAllGames :strTeamA :strTeamB];
        return cell1;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        if (cell2 == nil) {
            cell2 = (GoalsListCell *) [GoalsListCell cellFromNibNamed:@"GoalsListCell"];
        }
        [cell2 setDataInCell:arrGoalsList :[arrAllGames count]];
        return cell2;
    }
}

return nil;
```

}

Comment: Your code is invalid: `[cell2 setDataInCell:arrGoalsList:...]`

Comment: @ValentinShamardin this can be valid, in Objective-C you don't have to specify arguments name and you can call method like for example [self :par1 :par2];

Comment: this is the crash log
 Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:6509
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(

Comment: I think that problem is that i tried to get 2 diferent custom cells for 2 rows and problem is in that function can get the cell that was ask for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incorrect. You must dequeue the cell of this row with this identifier.
If you have only one section in the table, you don't need to do the indexPath.section check. Try this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"MatchDetail";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"GoalsList";
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
         //The first row is the MatchDetailsCell
         MatchDetailsCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
         if(cell == nil) {
            //If cell not exists, you must create a new one
            cell = [[MatchDetailsCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
         }
         //Rest of your cell code here
         return cell;
    } else {
         //Rest of the cells are GoalsListCell
         GoalsListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
         if(cell == nil) {
             cell = [[GoalsListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
         }
         //Rest of your cell code here
         return cell;
    }

}
```

I don't have more information about your code, but maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try that, you shouldn't deque the cell first and after that you load it from nib.
If it doesn't work post crash log.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"MatchDetail";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"GoalsList";

if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        MatchDetailsCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        [cell1 setDataInCell:arrAllGames :strTeamA :strTeamB];
        return cell1;
    }
    else if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        GoalsListCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        [cell2 setDataInCell:arrGoalsList :[arrAllGames count]];
        return cell2;
    }
}

return nil;
```

Comment: didn't work
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UITableView.m:6509
2014-08-13 13:27:13.794 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: Have you added the cell to storyboard/nib?, Have you set up cell identifier to each cell?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       if ((indexPath.row%2)==0)   // for even rows, like 1,3,5,...
       {
         MyFirstCell *firstCell = (MyFirstCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyFirstCell"];

       if (firstCell == nil)
       {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyFirstCell" owner:self options:nil];
            firstCell = (MyFirstCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
       }
        return firstCell;
     }
     else    // for even rows, like 2,4,6,...
     {
        MySecondCell *secondCell = (MySecondCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MySecondCell"];

        if (secondCell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MySecondCell" owner:self options:nil];
            secondCell = (MySecondCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
        } 
        return secondCell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: My code is working proper. i tried it.. you can try it.. create a demo with my code... :-)